# Azure Data Factory ADFV2 Trigger Overlap

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

I have a ADFV2 trigger that runs every 2 minutes. The pipeline that is called usually takes just over a minute to run but sometimes it takes over 2 minutes but if that happens the trigger kicks in again and runs regardless of the previous trigger still running or not. Is there any way to stop this overlap?
The trigger needs to run every 2 minutes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concurrency setting in the pipeline definition. Set it to 1.  The trigger will create an event, but it will be set to Queued state until previous job completes

Comment: where is that setting?